# No entiendo el error que C# y el entorno de trabajo VisualStudio me esta generando

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy realizando un proyecto en C# utilizando programación en Capas, aunque conozco el lenguaje, poseo cero experiencia con .NET y me esta dando un error que aunque puede ser obvio, no le encuentro sentido.

> Error  **NETSDK1022**  Se incluyeron "Compile" elementos duplicados. El
>   SDK de .NET incluye "Compile" elementos de su directorio de proyecto
>   de manera  predeterminada. Puede quitar esos elementos del archivo de
>   proyecto o establecer la propiedad "EnableDefaultCompileItems" en
>   "false" si desea incluirlos explícitamente en el archivo de proyecto.
>   Para más información, consulte https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. Los
>   elementos duplicados eran: 'AccionesSQL.cs'; 'ExceptionFuec.cs';
>   'Fuec.cs'; 'Usuarios.cs'
>   C:\Users\NombreUsuario\Carpeta\NombreProyecto\Datos\Datos.csproj
>   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets
>   246

En la Capa que actualmente estoy trabajando es en la de Datos, y estoy intentando crear el .dll, su estuctura es la siguiente:

`Datos
|
|--Fuec.cs
|--Usuarios.cs
|--AccionesSQL.cs
|--ExceptionFuec.cs`

las clases `Usuarios.cs` y `Acciones.cs` heredan a `Fuec.cs` y `ExceptionFuec.cs` hereda de la clase `NpgsqlException`.

Espero que me  puedan ayudar a entender ese error y cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Aquí hay una solución: http://jameschambers.com/2017/11/duplicate-compile-items-included/

Comment: Luis, es mejor citar a la página y compartir la solución en forma de texto y no de enlace, puesto que si la página cae, tu respuesta carecería de sentido.

Comment: @Zeugirdor de hecho no es respuesta, conozco las reglas y por eso mismo lo puse solo como comentario, principalmente porque estoy desde el móvil. Si alguien mas quiere ponerlo como respuesta lo puede hacer. Aparte, una simple búsqueda en google le hubiese dado la solución o al menos varias soluciones.

Answer (score 1):

A mi tambien me paso lo mismo, lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

1. Clic derecho sobre el proyecto que está ocasionando el problema.
2. Clic en editar archivo de proyecto.
3. Eliminar del `ItamGroup` los archivos que te están ocasionando problemas.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="YourFolder\Namespace\ClassNameHere.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Referencia http://jameschambers.com/2017/11/duplicate-compile-items-included/

Créditos: [@Luis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/59172/luis)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

También es posible solucionar este error recurrente poniendo la siguiente configuración en el archivo del proyecto (.csproj):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Referencia: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1022